# How to process the api key via stripe?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to console.log the product listvI have stored in stripes dashboard but I have gotten stuck on how to process the api key, the command is failing due to not being authorized, how can I improve the code to get the api key to process?

Here  the node js back end code I am trying to console . log

```
const axios = require('axios');
// fetch to make the api call
const URL = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/products/';
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config({ path: './.env' }) 
const stripe = require('stripe')('Secret_key_here');

axios.get(URL)
  .then(response => { 
    console.log(response.json());
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Stripe provides [`stripe-node`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) library which you can use it directly to retrieve the product list with Node example [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/list?lang=node).

Answer (score 1):

The key to accessing Stripe's API is passing the correct authentication headers with your API requests. Stripe uses Bearer authentication. When using Axios, you need to include your secret API key in the headers.

```
 const axios = require('axios');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: './.env' });

const SECRET_KEY = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY; // It's better to store secret keys in environment variables.
const URL = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/products/';

axios.get(URL, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${SECRET_KEY}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
})
.then(response => { 
    console.log(response.data); // Axios uses `data` property, not `json()`
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: That helped me out, thank you.